# Determine the compositions $ R \circ S \ and \ S \circ R $ of two relations R and S

Tags: relations

Determine the compositions $ R \circ S \ and \ S \circ R $  of two relations R and S   given  by $ S=\{(x,y): \sqrt{|x|} \leq y \} \\ R= \{(x,y): x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1 \} $. $$ $$ I have found $ R \circ S=\{(x,z) : |z| \leq 1-x^{2} \}$. But I am not sure. Any help is appreciating,